# Spark Scala 26035582 Re-visited

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Whilst I understand the ouctome here, I cannot see how the highlighted aspects work.
Please, enlighten me

```
def isHeavy(inp: String) = inp.split(",").map(weights(_)).sum > 12
```

---

```
val input = List("a,b,c,d", "b,c,e", "a,c,d", "e,g") 
val splitSize = 10000 // specify some number of elements that fit in memory.

val numSplits = (input.size / splitSize) + 1 // has to be > 0.
val groups = sc.parallelize(input, numSplits) // specify the # of splits.

val weights = Array(("a", 3), ("b", 2), ("c", 5), ("d", 1), ("e", 9), ("f", 4), ("g", 6)).toMap

def isHeavy(inp: String) = inp.split(",").map(weights(_)).sum > 12
val result = groups.filter(isHeavy)
```

Comment: I don't know what the number in the title means, but I assume this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26035582/how-to-filter-a-rdd-according-to-a-function-based-another-rdd-in-spark

Comment: Indeed but I cannit add a comment to it

Comment: Please don't edit my post. Your comment was fine, but completely  unrelated to the initial question. I'd suggest you attempt to learn a little Scala because this isn't a Spark problem

Comment: Was mistake! I am pretty new to all this. Sorry.

Comment: Actually I am learning SCALA in the process of SPARK, they seem to go hand in hand in many cases.

Comment: Neither are capitalized. If you prefer Java or Python instead, then by all means, use those instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`weights` is a map keyed by strings

```
scala> weights
res13: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(e -> 9, f -> 4, a -> 3, b -> 2, g -> 6, c -> 5, d -> 1)
```

`inp.split(",")` will split the string, and the  `map` function iterates over those keys, converting each into the value of the `weights`  map for the respective key.

The underscore is a scala shortcut and can be written as such

```
inp.split(",").map(x => weights(x))
```

In other words, `val input = List("a,b,c,d")` becomes a list of numbers (3,2,5,1), which then get summed, and filtered out for those more than 12

For example,

```
scala> input.foreach(x => println(x.split(",").mkString))
abcd
bce
acd
eg

scala> input.foreach(x => println(x.split(",").map(weights(_)).mkString(",")))
3,2,5,1
2,5,9
3,5,1
9,6

scala> input.foreach(x => println(x.split(",").map(weights(_)).sum))
11
16
9
15

scala> input.foreach(x => {
     |     val sum = x.split(",").map(weights(_)).sum
     |     if (sum > 12) println(sum)
     | })
16
15
```

Comment: which one? My one? Still not getting it. I have the impression a JOIN is going on and a lkp. Correct? Due to toMap. What would the code look like without a def I now wonder.

Comment: Join? What are you talking about? There's no SQL happening here

Comment: I am pretty sure there is x.join(...) that does not need SQL Context or DFs. I have the feeling I am missing something here

Comment: I can also use a value.get to join in a less robust fashion

Comment: The clue I think I have overlooked is the .toMap

Comment: Yes, thanks I understand / understood all that, but I remember also using collectAsMap and using value.get bla bla as oppised to .join. I am sure it is the .toMap and thank you.

Comment: `collectAsMap` is an RDD operation. As I said before, your question was never really asking about Spark

Comment: Yes I have to technically conclude that is correct, but I use SPARK and SCALA. Again my apologies.